# Change spring application.properties environment in Jenkins

Tags: java, spring, maven, jenkins

Currently I'm using Jenkins as CI. I have two jobs created on Jenkins, one for development and one for test.

In the development job, I set up maven to build the spring project. After the project is built, it triggers the test job and deploys on the test environment.

Under my spring project path

```
src\main\resources\config
```

I have the following three application properties

```
application-dev.properties
application-test.properties
application.properties
```

I currently have

```
spring.active.profile=dev
```

in my applicaiton.properties file.

My goal is to use application-dev.properties in my development environment (so maven should run application-dev.properties under the development job in jenkins), and use applicaiton-test.properties in my test environment (maven should run application-test.properties under the test job).

I'm stuck with how to run application-test.properties under test job in jenkins. My test job in jenkins currently deploys the .jar file to the test environment.
I currently have the following in command line

```
\deploy.bat "%FILEPATH%" %ENV% [web IP Address]
```

where deploy.bat contains the key and URL, etc. used to deploy on the test environment.

I tried editing the command line to

```
java -jar application.jar -Dspring.profiles.active=test
  \deploy.bat "%FILEPATH%" %ENV% [web IP Address]
```

but it wouldn't work.

So in summary, my question is how to override application.properties with application-test.properties in test job in jenkins?

Comment: Don't put that in `application.properties` that is a very bad idea. Remove it and pass it as a command line argument instead.